# Laravel .env file returns wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

I've been trying to get data from my database in laravel 5.7.3, but it seems to be using the wrong database name, username and password as it returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `tasks`)
```

My .env file database section is also according to my needs and set like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mrdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

PS: My app environment is still local. I can also migrate and put in data into database with `artisan tinker` without issues, but cannot just fetch data from the database.

The only way it gets to work is to change `config/database.php` mysql section to my parameters, which I believe it isn't just right.

Why is the .env not wanting the change when the database is called?

Comment: Did you cache your config beforehand? `php artisan config:clear` or override with a new config cache `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Didn't do any caching

Comment: Did the caching and that did the trick

Comment: If you run multiple sites on single server you **need** to use `config:cache`, otherwise some sites will use the *wrong* .env file / per request. Also make sure you have `env()` only in the configuration files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel uses caching to speed up your sites loading times, one of the things laravel caches is the config files located in the `config/` directory. Most of these files do have references to the `.env` file by using the `env()` helper function.

One can create a config cache by using `php artisan config:cache` which will then be stored in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

To remove this specific cache you can use `php artisan config:clear`, to clear all cache use `php artisan cache:clear`.

Answer (score 2):

This is cache issue use these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

After that delete all cache file ie inside

```
storage/framework/views
```